# CSV + Ubuntu : how to convert a .txt to .csv

Tags: csv, ubuntu, text-files

I have a .txt file whose content is:

```
EMG data generated by the Myo Armband in response to different hand gestures used to control a prosthesis.
EMG data of the Myo Armband for the hand gesture that generates the cylindrical grasp in the prosthesis.

// 1 Reading of the 8 sensors, 100 samples per sensor
{{194, 182, 187, 202, 200, 221, 240, 229, 230, 236, 213, 198, 226, 259, 254, 256, 285, 274, 232, 217, 207, 187, 211, 205, 210, 228, 260, 255, 270, 269, 273, 219, 209, 191, 200, 205, 219, 236, 253, 259, 263, 281, 307, 294, 276, 251, 224, 164, 179, 207, 214, 233, 219, 212, 210, 254, 240, 248, 247, 262, 221, 226, 235, 242, 208, 211, 251, 241, 264, 274, 295, 255, 248, 217, 196, 149, 153, 151, 150, 162, 166, 196, 205, 214, 234, 240, 243, 240, 248, 246, 240, 211, 212, 203, 210, 231, 244, 257, 289, 264},
{419, 437, 383, 407, 440, 426, 432, 433, 427, 424, 407, 458, 468, 485, 455, 436, 381, 365, 317, 319, 295, 247, 322, 331, 365, 420, 445, 454, 451, 431, 411, 388, 354, 345, 356, 307, 298, 290, 335, 344, 385, 460, 439, 414, 389, 347, 288, 303, 310, 316, 349, 355, 356, 354, 342, 419, 424, 410, 414, 407, 329, 273, 303, 308, 311, 312, 337, 384, 389, 378, 358, 349, 252, 223, 222, 243, 230, 249, 255, 279, 279, 359, 359, 426, 455, 458, 412, 427, 383, 349, 333, 350, 342, 323, 346, 365, 347, 369, 392, 366},
{170, 180, 174, 202, 201, 210, 191, 197, 222, 240, 229, 250, 260, 217, 203, 222, 207, 181, 166, 158, 119, 102, 111, 121, 147, 156, 155, 161, 168, 178, 172, 174, 172, 170, 145, 142, 157, 144, 144, 149, 156, 158, 172, 164, 157, 178, 177, 192, 222, 241, 241, 246, 238, 226, 204, 225, 231, 228, 233, 240, 210, 198, 193, 171, 181, 178, 192, 220, 220, 221, 214, 196, 193, 191, 193, 242, 267, 262, 268, 263, 253, 226, 232, 252, 255, 229, 232, 233, 219, 213, 217, 220, 218, 212, 208, 193, 193, 181, 196, 208},
{552, 492, 477, 473, 382, 510, 523, 539, 506, 526, 413, 449, 452, 533, 548, 610, 635, 644, 668, 664, 598, 667, 728, 661, 696, 741, 632, 552, 564, 596, 620, 654, 683, 712, 665, 600, 612, 585, 609, 564, 561, 520, 546, 459, 522, 592, 611, 600, 636, 614, 711, 777, 846, 829, 833, 761, 684, 607, 626, 689, 715, 721, 684, 716, 646, 541, 587, 615, 561, 606, 692, 665, 680, 665, 638, 555, 552, 552, 569, 579, 580, 577, 585, 640, 698, 688, 729, 696, 645, 540, 523, 508, 566, 561, 565, 603, 558, 530, 594, 631},
{360, 343, 339, 354, 325, 372, 378, 378, 337, 340, 289, 298, 292, 342, 356, 372, 368, 392, 481, 479, 454, 498, 502, 382, 404, 441, 376, 368, 389, 399, 436, 470, 469, 487, 469, 419, 410, 417, 409, 390, 424, 427, 421, 433, 467, 527, 529, 535, 518, 501, 559, 595, 633, 620, 628, 528, 461, 407, 428, 464, 477, 475, 452, 457, 426, 357, 429, 436, 424, 403, 436, 391, 408, 404, 420, 397, 405, 412, 426, 425, 441, 417, 452, 469, 529, 531, 563, 537, 514, 448, 412, 417, 443, 463, 441, 449, 447, 396, 434, 450},
{110, 106, 117, 121, 119, 131, 130, 120, 118, 134, 113, 126, 123, 122, 112, 121, 113, 130, 180, 182, 182, 189, 189, 137, 129, 136, 122, 120, 132, 141, 149, 157, 153, 155, 151, 144, 141, 142, 135, 131, 140, 141, 140, 151, 163, 163, 174, 185, 181, 180, 220, 229, 223, 218, 216, 171, 139, 130, 134, 164, 170, 166, 165, 171, 150, 128, 147, 153, 142, 135, 150, 140, 138, 142, 141, 132, 129, 129, 129, 141, 151, 154, 170, 177, 186, 178, 197, 192, 193, 178, 174, 162, 161, 163, 155, 165, 156, 143, 163, 170},
{267, 284, 280, 281, 297, 258, 226, 239, 266, 293, 291, 314, 303, 285, 272, 307, 297, 305, 317, 296, 328, 344, 352, 355, 384, 345, 320, 345, 362, 364, 350, 359, 357, 360, 355, 356, 367, 320, 287, 259, 258, 275, 299, 311, 318, 359, 369, 375, 370, 380, 357, 322, 288, 290, 299, 285, 293, 353, 354, 351, 334, 317, 279, 291, 300, 322, 341, 357, 353, 322, 340, 379, 361, 353, 345, 336, 292, 276, 301, 330, 314, 301, 327, 319, 337, 365, 374, 378, 473, 548, 536, 563, 560, 500, 384, 403, 363, 362, 401, 446},
{271, 271, 265, 272, 294, 295, 289, 301, 377, 379, 372, 378, 404, 321, 357, 356, 394, 362, 378, 336, 327, 285, 286, 288, 314, 333, 354, 365, 359, 368, 352, 321, 435, 468, 507, 537, 551, 461, 475, 431, 413, 423, 484, 441, 432, 402, 425, 347, 396, 383, 398, 386, 401, 347, 339, 338, 301, 294, 290, 356, 336, 333, 339, 355, 326, 362, 417, 451, 474, 441, 434, 471, 438, 426, 452, 442, 346, 323, 363, 378, 385, 402, 419, 401, 413, 409, 450, 479, 503, 528, 543, 510, 470, 465, 403, 422, 404, 442, 453, 455}}
```

How to produce a .csv (just with the numerical values) out of it ?

Comment: CSV = Comma Separated Values. I would try to use SED and RegEx to remove everything except numeric values and commas. http://www.theunixschool.com/2014/08/sed-examples-remove-delete-chars-from-line-file.html

Comment: @Debbie Did any of the answers below resolve your question?

Comment: I'm yet to check. If any of those resolves my problem even partially, I'll mark that as answer.

Comment: @Debbie Cool, let us know

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first get rid of the four header lines, and then replace all characters other than a comma or a number with nothing:

```
sed -e '1,4d' < inputFile.txt | sed 's/[^,0-9]//g' > inputFile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
tail -n +5 input.txt | sed -r 's/(\{|\})//g;s/,$//g' >out.csv
```